# Updating an array of objects with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update an array of objects on my model, Stuff.

My model:

```
var StuffSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  things: [Object]
});
```

In my route:

```
Stuff.update({"_id": req.params.id}), {$push: {"things": {$each: req.body.things}}}, function(err, raw) {
  console.log(raw);
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(true);
})
```

This throws the error:

`Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`

The output of the console.log is:

`{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

Hardcoding an array of objects gives the same results:

```
Stuff.update({"_id": req.params.id}), {$push: {"things": {$each: [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 3, b: 4}]}}}, function(err, raw) {
  console.log(raw);
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(true);
})
```

However, if I instead just update the name field:

```
Stuff.update({"_id": req.params.id}), {"name": "fancy pants"}, function(err, raw) {
  console.log(raw);
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(true);
})
```

This properly updates the Stuff document and the output of the console.log is:

`{ n: 1, nModified: 0, opTime: { ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1513093848 }, t: 1 }, electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000001, ok: 1 }`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `No default engine was specified and no extension was provided` means that when you want to render a view you have to provide at least a file with its extension :

```
res.render('index.html');
```

**Or** set a default view engine, like this:

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
```

Also in your `StuffSchema` change `Object` type to `Mixed`:

```
var StuffSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    things: [Schema.Types.Mixed]
});
```

Comment: Switching to `Schema.Types.Mixed` did the trick! The Mongoose docs claim that `Schema.Types.Mixed`, `Object`, and `{}` are equivalent, but apparently that's not the case.